# Projection on a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to find the coordinates of the projection of a point (x,y,z) on a plane.

In $A^3(C)$ let  $p$ be the plane of equation $2x+y-1=0$

Calculate the coordinates of $p_u(x,y,z)$ where: $p_u:A^3\longrightarrow p$ is the projection, $(x,y,z) \in A^3$ is a variable point and $u \in C^3$ is the vector $(1,0,0)$

My attempt is:

if I call $Q(x_Q,y_Q,z_Q) $ the point of intersection of the projection with the plane and $P(x,y,z)$ the projection point,  $\vec {PQ} =\vec {Q} -\vec {P}=t*\vec {u}  $ because $\vec {u}$ is a base of its associated subspace

$(x-x_Q,y-y_Q,z-z_Q)=t*(1,0,0)$

$\begin{cases}x=x_Q+1*t \\
y=y_Q+0*t \\z=z_Q+0*t \end{cases}$

$Q \in p \Rightarrow 2*x_Q+y_Q-1=0 \Rightarrow x_Q=1/2-y_Q/2$

$\begin{cases}x=\frac{1-y_Q}{2}+t \\
y=y_Q \\z=z_Q \end{cases}$ 
But the solution in my book is $(\frac{1-y}{2},y,z)$ without the parameter t.

Comment: Because the answer must be the point $Q$, whereas your last set of coordinates is the coordinates of the point $P$.

Comment: With the parameter $t$ you have a line, not a point.

Comment: @AMD Could you be more clear? Ho would you solve it?

Comment: @zipirovich in any case t doesn't disappear

Answer (score 1):

As zipirovich points out in a comment to your question, you’ve written down an expression for the point $P$, not the point $Q$. Moreover, you’ve made a sign error, although not one that’s going to throw things off too much: in your question you write that $\vec Q-\vec P=t\cdot(1,0,0)$, but the l.h.s. of the next equation is $\vec P-\vec Q$ instead.

So, you need to fix this sign error and write $Q$ in terms of $P$, not the other way around. Obviously, you’ll still have $y_Q=y$ and $z_Q=z$, but I’ll leave finding an expression for $x_Q$ in terms of $x$, $y$ and $z$ up to you. Once you’ve done that, you will likely still need to eliminate $t$, but that’s easy: for what value of $t$ does $Q-Q=t\cdot(1,0,0)$?

Comment: for $ t=0$. I think to have understood this case. The exercise follows with another vector $u= (2i,i,1) $ Can you help me?

Comment: @Anne What is $i$ here?

Comment: we're in the Field of complex number

Comment: @Anne Solve it the same way, except that now you have to work with complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You have $x_Q=\frac 1 2 - \frac {y_Q} 2$ and $y=y_Q$ therefore $x_Q=\frac {1-y} 2$